# How to avoid an hover on a menu item to affect the menu items on the right

Tags: css, hover

I have an extremely simple horizontal menu. I wanted to font to become bold on hover. The thing is when I make the hover the text becomes bold but all menu items on the right switch to the right by few pixels. Hope someone can help me understand how to avoid that. thank you.

FIDDLE : : http://jsfiddle.net/QKBUS/

HTML :

```
<div id="header">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li class="bouton_gauche"><a href="">agenda</a></li>
    <li class="bouton_gauche"><a href="">messagerie</a></li>
    <li class="bouton_gauche"><a href="">communautée</a></li>
    <li class="bouton_gauche"><a id="btn-deconnexion" href="">déconnexion</a></li>
    <li class="bouton_droite"><a href="">[logo]</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

CSS :

```
ul#menu { 
list-style-type : none; 
}

li.bouton_gauche {
float : left;
margin-right:15px;
}

li.bouton_droite {
float : right;
}

ul#menu a{
text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu a:hover{
font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Comment: Well, the width of each menu item comes from the width of the text inside, and the text becomes wider when bold.

Comment: hello. the thing is i can't have a standard width as each text has a different length. it would look wierd...

Comment: Why don't you just add the proper width to every li.bouton_gauche so it can contein the bold text ?

Comment: hi vucko, check my previous answer to thirtydot

Comment: It looks weird no matter what you do. For example, here's a JavaScript fix: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QKBUS/15/. The width between each menu item is different, and it looks bad. It's slightly better with `text-align: center`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QKBUS/18/

Comment: ty. if you put that as an answer i will accept it. exactly what i wanted (the second fiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist... http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QKBUS/18/

Add `text-align: center` to `ul#menu`, then use this JavaScript (uses jQuery):

```
$('#header li a').each(function() {
    var temp = $(this).hide().clone().appendTo($(this).parent()).css('font-weight', 'bold').show();
    $(this).show().parent().width(temp.width());
    temp.remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The above can be easily avoided by giving a fix width to the list items but that would make the first one look too off from others, so you will have to use different width for the first one.

Comment: Too true about the too off part. And then what about if it is a dynamic menu where long and short menu item names can come up? Better go with something that is not limited to static content. But yes, your observation is exactly what this is about.